# PHP Inserting variable inside EOT

Tags: php, variables

I want to insert a variable inside the EOT but is not working (I am new to php, maybe that's why). This code is part of a script, when I echo `$username` alone it shows the real name, but when I put it inside EOT is displaying plain text not the real name..

What am I doing wrong?

```
$username=getUsername($ID);

echo <<<'EOT'

Some HTML code goes here

Hello $username, welcome back!

Some HTML code goes here

EOT;
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You must leave out the single quotes here:

```
echo <<<'EOT'
```

This denotes the ['nowdoc'](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) variant, which doesn't interpolate variables.

But you need the original ["heredoc"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax without quotes:

```
echo <<<EOT
```

Comment: Yep, is working now.. Thanks a lot for explaining the hieroglyphs for me :)

Comment: Oh, btw, you don't *have to* name it `EOT`. You can use any delimiter string that you like. It's also common to use `echo <<<END` or `echo <<<HTML` (with `HTML;` after the text block).

Comment: Please select this as the solution, for which it clearly is.  Thx.

Answer (score 14):

```
$variable = 'text';
echo <<<EOT
Some {$variable} here
EOT;
```

Comment: Could you add some words that explain why you think that this is a solution?

Comment: I happen to find the same issue and this is how I resolved it. Putting {} around variables does substitute var names for their values.